# how to rearrange the order of the output in magento?

Tags: php, magento

the default style is as this:
[image]

now i want to put the  `How do you rate this product? *` part(the following image with red color marked) on the comment form. how do i do? thank you.

[image]

Comment: it's like a mysterious :) where is the code part of the rating section? Which template responsible of the rate section etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest way to do this is search for "How do you rate this product" in your code base. Hopefully you will find a .phtml file where this code sits. Then change the wrap this line with span style = red
**How do you rate this product?***

. Good luck.